# Cant retrieve PHP arrays outside the assigning loop

Tags: php

I am trying to create a 2-dimensional array, reading specific values from a (large) met file. The arrays are empty and I dont know why.
I have the following array:

`$varmet = array('tasmax', 'tasmin', 'pr', 'clt');`

I have two loops:

The first is

```
for ($j = 0; $j <= 3; $j++)  {
...
```

I read the corresponding files and variables, etc. It works properly.

Then I have the other loop

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 360; $i++) {
....
$valor = $valor * $correctp;
```

It works perfectly, retrieving the required value in $valor

The problem arise when I want to store the value in a different array, according to the met variable:

```
switch ($j) {
case 0: 
   $tmax[$i] = $valor;
break;
case 1: 
   $tmin[$i] = $valor;
break;
case 2: 
   $prec[] = $valor;
break;
case 3: 
   $clt[$i] = $valor;
break; } // Fin del switch

    }  // Fin del for para un fichero met
} // Fin del for para todas las varmet
```

The `$tmax`, `$tmin`, etc. have no value, although $valor does have. Furthermore, if I assign the array within the loop (i.e. `$valorest[$j][$i] = $valor`) it still have the values, but not outside it.

Anybody knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please show us your complete code, not only bits and pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$tmax = array(); //declare this outside the loop i.e before the loop starts
```

In switch case statement, replace the below line

```
$tmax[$i] = $valor;
```

with

```
array_push($tmax,$valor);
```